# Not able to retrieve data after a search task in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, automation, youtube

I am using learning selenium and stuck around. I opened youtube with and then a searched a word in the search bar

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

search = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "search_query")
search.send_keys("Python")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

After this I tried to retrieve the data of the whole page which is under an id "contents" and print that

```
main = driver.find_element(By.ID, "contents")
print(main.text)
```

What it did was just give the data in the same id name of the previous page. I stopped the program for 5 sec to let the page load, but then the output was just two blank lines

```
time.sleep(5)
main = driver.find_element(By.ID, "contents")
print(main.text)
```

If I try to directly opened up the second page, it would give me the expected results

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Python")
main = driver.find_element(By.ID, "contents")
print(main.text)
```

I am not able to get the reason. I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint is less error-prone.

Comment: I actually want to do it without using any API, just selenium and search the elements